# Styles in CSS ignored following switch to multisite structure

Tags: 7, theming, multi-sites

Following a switch from a single site structure to a multisite structure, many of the styles in my theme stylesheet (including overridden styles from various module themes) are now being ignored. Is there any way I can make sure my theme stylesheet takes precedence over anything else?

Comment: It would be helpful to have more info about the site folders.  eg. where is the theme sheet and where are the individual sites.

Comment: what is the drupal version, are you using base themes, have you cleared cache?